# How to abstract a JavaScript file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, mobile, browser

I've got a difficult question.
I could not find an answer on the internet...so this is my last chance.

I would like to realize the following scenario:

- One File JavaScript that is "abstract", i.e., when the client is mobile, I use mobile Javascript implementation; otherwise I use the classic one.

In other words:

How can I create an A.js file with functions\Other (For example a `HelloWorld()`) and, by delegation or inheritance (or other solution that I ignore)? Can I use the `HelloWorld()` of A-mobile.js or the `HelloWorld()` of A-classic.js?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: are we talking about client javascript or java?

Comment: .jar file is Java, not javascript. You should first know what you exactly want before asking...

Comment: Jar files have absolutely nothing to do with JavaScript...

Comment: Pick a high-level wrapper for your JavaScript, like Typescript, and then it is easy to use basic *class inheritance* to extend behavior as you suggest. You *can* do it in raw JS, but harder to read/write :)

Comment: Sorry it was only a lapsus, a mistake. I mean JAVASCRIPT, so .js file :) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you want solve this on class level of your javascript. Instead, use different JS file for mobile and full versions. You can do this on server side (render different HTML script tag for each) or on client (javascript can load another javascript like this:

```
if (mobile){
  var fileref=document.createElement('script')
  fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript")
  fileref.setAttribute("src", mobileJsFilename)
  document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref)
 }
```

As for detecting mobile browser, look here : http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/